# Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction due to ora 12519

Tags: spring, oracle, ora-12519

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection due to TNS:no appropriate service handler found.

I am getting, ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found. error in spring web application. It works perfectly right but after some time it crashes giving ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found error. Note: My web page is refreshing automatically after 5 sec (as per my need). I had used transaction annotation over the service layer.

Mar 18, 2019 8:48:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/springBRD] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
localhost:1521:orcl

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:261)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:441)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.extractPhysicalConnection(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:82)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:138)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:147)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:166)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:145)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1854)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1831)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2516)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2502)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2332)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2327)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:490)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1247)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
at com.nucleus.dao.CustomerDAOImp.getAllCustomer(CustomerDAOImp.java:95)
at com.nucleus.service.CustomerServiceImp.getAllCustomer(CustomerServiceImp.java:51)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor52.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.getAllCustomer(Unknown Source)
at com.nucleus.controller.UserController.showall(UserController.java:166)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am using Localhost to run the app. I have found the cause of app crash. Its because when my page fresh after 5 sec it requests data from oracle db. So, an new session is created for it every 5 sec. When too many sessions it created then it gives then excepion.

but, how to solve this problem in spring and hibernate. I am using bean of session factory and injecting it in dao layer. So, new connection/session should not be created. Pls help...

Comment: Give us an overview of your setup: Which Spring boot version, which Oracle version? What have you done so far to remedy the problem? How does it crash? Can you provide stack traces?

Comment: I am using Spring 3.5 not Spring boot. And Oracle 11g.

Comment: Well thank you for your comments. Could you please put them directly in your question, that it is easier for all of us to help?